# AVPlayer error while playing on tvOS

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, tvos, avplayerlayer

I'm playing a video on tvOS using the following code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileUrl];
AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];

avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
[view.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(replayMovie:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];

[self.player play];
```

But I'm getting the following error

> ERROR:    >aqme> 718: MEMixerChannel::EnableProcessor: failed to open
>   processor type 0x705f6571

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you running the app in the simulator or on the Apple TV dev kit?

For tvOS, most AV related bugs/crashes I've encountered only occur when I'm using the Apple TV simulator - once I run the app on the physical device, they tend to disappear.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running it on the simulator. I thought that it might be the case. Unfortunately I don't have Applet TV yet to test it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Wojtek Did you see my answer? I got the code working fine in the simulator.

Comment: @ABeanSits Did you see my question? I posted code there, your answer is exactly the same code just in Swift...

Answer (score 4):

I'm getting a video to load and play locally on the simulator. 
I wrote it in Swift but you should be able to translate it fairly easy.

```
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("4", ofType:"mp4") {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
        playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        videoPlayer.play()
    }
```

Make sure `fileUrl` is not `nil` and try removing code that is not needed (like the notification-part) so we can deduce which part is failing.

I'm using Xcode 7.1beta3.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to subclass AVPlayerViewController. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/):

> IMPORTANT
>
> Do not subclass AVPlayerViewController. Overriding this class’s
>   methods is unsupported and results in undefined behavior.

Instead, use a regular UIViewController, and then attach the AVPlayerViewController's view to it.

Using @AbeanSits's code (I'm using RubyMotion, but you can translate to Obj-C) worked. Here's my version:

```
  def viewDidAppear(_)
    super

    @player_controller = AVPlayerViewController.alloc.init
    @player_controller.player = AVPlayer.alloc.initWithURL(current_url)
    self.addChildViewController(@player_controller)
    self.view.addSubview(@player_controller.view)
    @player_controller.view.frame = self.view.frame
    @player_controller.player.play
  end
```